# Is there an option in clang format to put the initializer lists of constructors on the next line in C++?

Tags: c++, clang-format

Clang format formats this:

```
Rect(Pos pos, Dim dim)
  : m_pos(pos), m_dim(dim) {}
```

to this:

```
Rect(Pos pos, Dim dim) : m_pos(pos), m_dim(dim) {}
```

is there an option where you can say that the initializer list of constructors should break before the `:` in clang format?

This is my .clang-format file

```
Language: Cpp
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
IndentCaseLabels: true
NamespaceIndentation: All
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: Yes
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: All
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeColon
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
```

Edit: The first example is an example of the formatting I want. The second example is what clang-format does to my code.

Comment: Should not the last be true?

Comment: @S.M. Why? OP doesn't want one initialiser per line.

Comment: @eerorika it will only put one initialiser per line if all initializer do not fit into a single line. For OP example, these will stay in one line. But for bigger list, it will be splitted in multiple lines (imho should be the case for readability)

Comment: @NicolasDusart in op's example of undesired formatting, the initialisers are already on a single line. so how does the setting that keeps them on single line help?

Comment: Ummm... I think the question is a bit unclear as to which formatting I want and which I don't I've updated the question so that its a bit more clear.